# Rethrow exception with async task?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        //Call WebApi...
    }, token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oex)
{ }
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

The method within `await` either returns code 200 or throws a particular exception that I want to evaluate.

As the action is cancelable, an `OperationCanceledException` might be thrown and I just want to ignore it.

The above should work. However is it possible to consolidate both `catch` statements with the new C# 6.0 syntax by using `when`?

Comment: tried looking at this: http://druss.co/2015/05/c-6-0-exception-filters-try-catch-when/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need C# 6, just get rid of the last catch block and have only the `OperationCanceledException`

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        //Call WebApi...
    }, token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oex)
{ }
```

The one thing you might want to do with C# 6 is check that the token that was used to raise the excption is the token you passed in

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        //Call WebApi...
    }, token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oex) when (oex.CancellationToken == token)
{ }
```

Or using the old style

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        //Call WebApi...
    }, token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oex)
{ 
    if(oex.CancellationToken != token)
        throw;
}
```

Comment: Would the second suggestion rethrow the original exception "as-is" as I need to evaluate the exact exception thrown from the webapi method?

Comment: Yes, any exception not matched in the `when` will bubble up to the next try/catch block unmodified. Using `when` does not really provide any benifit over the old style for your specific case, the only way you would get a benefit of something you could not do in C# 5 is if you did some additional work in the "catch all" exception, for example logging. With the `when` you could get a `OperationCanceledException` to go to your default catch block, with the old style you would have to write your logging code in both the default catch block and the catch for `OperationCanceledException`.